# C string to keep macro definition

Tags: c, gcc, visual-studio-2013

I am trying below code using compilers MSVC 2013 and GCC.

```
#define AV_FFMPEG_SAMPLE( ... )# __VA_ARGS__

const char *function_store = AV_FFMPEG_SAMPLE(

#define BUF_SIZE 65536
#define ALIGN_MASK 0xFF00

int foo()
{
  int abc;
  int *xyz;

  xyz = (int *)malloc(BUF_SIZE);
  return (BUF_SIZE & ALIGN_MASK);
}
);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    printf("%s\n", function_store);
}
```

**MSVC 2013 Output:**

> #define BUF_SIZE 65536 #define ALIGN_MASK 0xFF00 int foo() {int abc; int *xyz; xyz = (int *)malloc( BUF_SIZE); return (BUF_SIZE & ALIGN_MASK); }

**GCC Output:**

> int foo() { int abc; int *xyz; xyz = (int *)malloc(BUF_SIZE); return
>   (BUF_SIZE & ALIGN_MASK); }

My preferred output is same as MSVC 2013 output, but I need to get the same using **GCC (MinGW)**. How can I get the output similar to  **MSVC 2013 output**, using **GCC (MinGW)**?

Comment: Maybe move the macro definitions out of the parantheses.

Comment: This looks like a good example how **not** to use macros. You cannot use `#define` inside macro expansion. the `#` must not be past the macro name/parenthesis. You better state what you want to accomplish. It might eb an XY-problem. MSVC is not even compatible to C99, not to speak of the current standard C11.

Comment: Oh, and: Do not cast the result of `malloc` & friends in C!

Comment: Olaf, I need to hold a program as string (including all the macros, inline functions etc) and then pass this string pointer to another compiler-Y. Compiler-Y takes this string and compiles it. I am getting issue in GCC as it excludes macro definition as part of string. How can I accomplish this, independent of compiler that I choose?

Answer (score 1):

C specifies of a function-like macro invocation that

> If there are sequences of preprocessing tokens within the list of arguments that would otherwise act as preprocessing directives, the behavior is undefined.

(C 2011 6.10.3/11, and identical in C99 6.10.3/11).

That's exactly your situation.  Since stringification applies only in the context of a function-like macro replacement list, and behavior is (explicitly) undefined for the case that the macro arguments comprise tokens that otherwise would constitute preprocessing directives, you're pretty much at the mercy of whatever compiler you choose.  There is no reliable way to achieve what you say you want.

If what you want most is consistent output regardless of which compiler builds your code, then move the macro definitions out of the scope of the invocation of `AV_FFMPEG_SAMPLE()`.

Frankly, although I don't have much regard for VS 2013 from a standards-conformance perspective, I tend to think more highly of GCC.  Does it not warn about your code?

Comment: John, I appreciate your answer. But my objective is to keep the macro definitions also as part of the C-string. If I move my macro definitions "out of the scope of the invocation of AV_FFMPEG_SAMPLE()", then I can not achieve what I wanted to. In my case, this C-string gets picked up by some other compiler and try to compile. Since the macro definitions get away by first compiler, string getting ripped off before getting passed to second compiler. When second compiler try to compile the passed C-string, it fails due to absence of macro definitions.

Comment: @ARK, then you cannot achieve what you want to, period, unless you happen to get lucky with the chosen compiler.  Compilers aren't obligated even to accept your code at all.  If they do accept it, they aren't required to do any particular thing with it, nor always do the same thing with it.  The behavior is *undefined*.